# Access a panel from another form with increment variable name

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub StatusLoad(ByVal id As String)
    ''Dim F As New Apps
    ''Dim W As Panel = DirectCast(F.Controls(id), Panel)

    Dim count As Long = 0

    Dim strQueryStat As String = "SELECT * FROM sample_db.ronda WHERE id = '" + id + "'"

    Dim SqlCmdStat As New MySqlCommand(strQueryStat, dbCon)

    Reader = SqlCmdStat.ExecuteReader


    While Reader.Read
        count = count + 1
        MsgBox("id" & count)
        Dim status_db = Reader.GetString("status")

        If status_db = 0 Then
            Apps.id.BackColor = Color.Green '<------
            MsgBox("Green")
        Else
            Apps.BackColor = Color.Red
            MsgBox("Red")

        End If
    End While

End Sub
```

I want to use 'id' variable that get from other form to find the panel name from the other form. the above code is in a class. the panel that i want to access is at another form.
at the other for i send "con.StatusLoad(id)". the name of panel is id1 , id2 , id3 ...... the error is at the arrow

```
Private Sub app_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ManageConnection(False)
    For index As Integer = 1 To 2
        Dim id As String = "id" & index
        con.StatusLoad(id)
    Next index
End Sub
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

Each control, including forms, has a `Controls` property that contains a collection of child controls.  You can index that collection by ordinal or name, e.g.

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Dim pnl = Me.Controls("Panel" & i)

    '...
Next
```

Note that you'll be getting a `Control` reference back, so you can only use it to access members of the `Control` class.  If you want to access members of a specific type of control then you must cast as that type.

`Controls` is a public member so it can be accessed from outside the form but probably shouldn't be.  The same "rules" apply as would always apply to making changes to controls on a form, i.e. best practice dictates that it's done inside that form only.